# How to make a resizable gauge with QML - text size problem

Tags: qt, qml, resizable, gauge

I am trying to make a resizable gauge (audio fader like in the image below) with Gauge / GaugeStyle.

Tickmarks shall be left and right of the fader.

Somehow I am unable to find a way to correctly change the pointSize / pixelSize of the tickmark labels.

I am wrapping my head around this for days now but, most likely due to lack of experience and/or know-how of QML, I can't get that to work.
The program starts with a 'middle-sized' window and I want to resize it larger and smaller to a minimum/maximum height/width.

I am pretty sure there are better solutions that might work out of the box than mine, but I couldn't find something matching.

Whenever I resize the window to its max height, the tickmark labels get (slightly) out of their vertical center position.

So I'd appreciate any help getting me to where I want.

Or would it be better/easier to just use a prepared image which will be resized correctly ?
I don't think there's any performance impact since the window will not be resized very often during the run of the program.

I already tried a bunch of things even to split the tickmark area into rows/columns to get this going. Text.Fit dosen't work either the way I want it to.

I am using Qt 5.12.3 with Qt Creator 4.9.1 on macOS 10.12.6

Here's my code :

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Window
{
    id              : myMainWindow
    visible         : true
    width           : 400
    height          : 400
    minimumHeight   : 300
    minimumWidth    : 300
    maximumHeight   : 800
    maximumWidth    : 800
    title: qsTr("Gauge Test")

    Gauge
    {
        id: myGauge
        height : parent.height
        scale: 0.9
        width: parent.width / 3
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter    

        minimumValue: -20
        maximumValue: 70
        minorTickmarkCount: 0
        value: 0

        font.family: "Tahoma"

        style: GaugeStyle
        {
            id: myGaugeStyle

            valueBar : Item { visible : false}

            tickmark : Item
            {
                id: myTickmarks
                implicitHeight: Math.max(myMainWindow.height/ 200,1)
                width : myGauge.width / 5

                Rectangle
                {
                    id:leftDash
                    implicitHeight: Math.max(myMainWindow.height/ 200,1)
                    width : myGauge.width / 5
                    anchors.left: myTickmarks.left
                    anchors.leftMargin: myGauge.width / 5
                    color: "blue"
                }

                Rectangle
                {
                    id:noDash
                    anchors.left : leftDash.right
                    implicitHeight: Math.max(myMainWindow.height/ 200,1)
                    width : myGauge.width / 5
                    color: "transparent"
                }

                Rectangle
                {
                    id:rightDash
                    implicitHeight: Math.max(myMainWindow.height/ 200,1)
                    width : myGauge.width / 5
                    anchors.left : noDash.right
                    color: "blue"
                }
            }

            // Does not work as expected
            /*
            tickmarkLabel: Text
            {
                id: myTickmarkLabel
                text: styleData.value
                font.pointSize : Math.max(
                    Math.sqrt(myMainWindow.width * myMainWindow.height * 0.8 ) / 26
                    ,6)
                // verticalAlignment : Text.AlignVCenter
                color: "blue"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: font.pointSize
                // anchors.rightMargin : font.pointSize
                // anchors.topMargin : font.pointSize
                // anchors.bottomMargin : font.pointSize
            }
            */

            // Works pretty well : 
            tickmarkLabel: Text
            {
               id: myTickmarkLabel
               text: styleData.value

               transform: Scale 
               {
                  xScale: 3 * myMainWindow.width / myMainWindow.maximumWidth
                  yScale: 3 * myMainWindow.height / myMainWindow.maximumHeight 
               }

               color: "blue"
               anchors.left: parent.left
               anchors.leftMargin: myMainWindow.width / myMainWindow.maximumWidth
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id: middleRect
        height: parent.height
        width : parent.width / 3
        anchors.left: myGauge.right
        color : "steelblue"
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rightRect
        height: parent.height
        width : parent.width / 3
        anchors.left: middleRect.right
        color : "grey"
    }
}
```

As said, I cannot align the tickmark labels correctly for all sizes the window can have.

Here's an image of what the fader shall look like:

[image]

Comment: what does `Math.sqrt(myMainWindow.width * myMainWindow.height * 0.8 ) / 26` mean?

Comment: I tried to find a formula that comes closest to the relation between changing only the size, only the height or both at the same time, of the main window. Based on the relation between height and size, I try to calculate the pointSize for the font that fits best. It's just trial and error.

Comment: Looks strange ... if you, for example increase only height *2 you font will increase too but the width remains the same. I would use Item.scale for this purposes and at least check the Gauge source

Comment: Thanks for the input - just found out yesterday that there's something like that - will try to use it and to understand the Gauge source.

Comment: Scaling an object (text also) with different scaling factors for height and width can be done with : transform: Scale (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-scale.html). This enables me to keep the value of the other size when scaling either height or width - and both of them at the same time as well. I added the code to my example code. The tickmarks don't align to the text anyway at this point. But at least I found a solution for the text scaling. I will now focus on the alignment of both items ....